# Get the text value of a link via firefox context menu

Tags: firefox-addon

How do I get the title of a link element when right clicking in firefox?

I can get the url using:

`gContextMenu.linkURL`

I have tried the following to get the value but it returns nothing.

`gContextMenu.target.value`

I can't see any other property that would help in the docs: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/ContextMenus#Determining_what_was_Context_Clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course it should be: `gContextMenu.target.innerHTML` as the a element has no value attribute.

Comment: That would be the text of the link. The title would be `gContextMenu.target.getAttribute('title')`.

Comment: thanks, I realised that I wanted the value not the title. Will change the thread title to reflect it :)

Answer (score 0):

"Bookmark This Link" uses gContextMenu.linkText()